# How to combine to 2 select query values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My select query:

```
SELECT 
    ResultTag, Overallstatus, ProcessOrder  
FROM 
    Evaluation

UNION 

SELECT 
    '2' AS ResultTag,
    'Approve' AS Overallstatus,
    '6' AS ProcessOrder
```

Expected result:

```
----------  ----------     ----------
Result Tag  Overallstatus  ProcessOrder
----------  ----------     ----------
0            Approved        1
1            Reject          2
.                            . 
.                            .
2            Approve         6
```

I need to combine the results of both the select queries. I tried using `UNION` but it results in only the first query output.

Thanks in advance for you help..

Comment: UNION combines the results, UNION ALL does so including duplicates, perhaps that is the issue, it can't be anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `Union` to `union All`, if you have a diplicate rows, but something is wrong if there isnt any duplicate and you dont get second query result

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL Statement :

```
  SELECT ResultTag,Overallstatus,ProcessOrder  
  FROM Evaluation
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' AS ResultTag,'Approve' AS Overallstatus,'6' AS ProcessOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

The result might have duplicates, use UNION ALL

```
    SELECT 
      ResultTag,Overallstatus,ProcessOrder  from Evaluation

        UNION ALL

 SELECT 
     '2' AS ResultTag,
     'Approve' AS Overallstatus,
     '6' AS ProcessOrder
```